# How to deserialize a RecordBatch from a pyarrow Buffer

Tags: python, pyarrow

My goal is to serialize a `RecordBatch`, send it on a websocket channel
and deserialize it on the receiver side.

On the receiver side, after receiving the data packet and reconstructing
a `pyarrow.lib.Buffer` object with `pa.py_buffer`, I'm
not able to deserialize it back to a `RecordBatch`.

Keeping off websocket's boilerplate this a snippet that summarize what I'm trying to do:

```
import pyarrow as pa

indicators = [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B')]

id = pa.int16()
name = pa.string()

data = pa.array(indicators, type=pa.struct([('id', id), ('name', name)]))

batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays([data], ['indicators'])

buffer = batch.serialize()

# How to get back a RecordBatch from buffer?
#
# ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `serialize` method like that, you can use the `read_record_batch` function *given* a known schema:

```
>>> pa.ipc.read_record_batch(buffer, batch.schema)
<pyarrow.lib.RecordBatch at 0x7ff412257278>
```

But that means you need to know the schema on the receiving side. To encapsulate this in the serialized data, use `RecordBatchStreamWriter` instead:

```
>>> sink = pa.BufferOutputStream()
>>> writer = pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(sink, batch.schema)
>>> writer.write_batch(batch)
>>> writer.close()
>>> buf = sink.getvalue()
```

```
>>> reader = pa.ipc.open_stream(buf)
>>> reader.read_all()
pyarrow.Table
indicators: struct<id: int16, name: string>
  child 0, id: int16
  child 1, name: string
```

See the docs at https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html